# Stacking Widgets for dynamic form generation in GTK#

Tags: .net, scrollbar, gtk#

Right now I'm developing a .NET Mono GTK# application that dynamically generates its widgets based on a XML file. So I need to stack a bunch of widgets one below another. I tried using VBox (as I need the widgets to stretch horizontally) but I don't want the widgets to stretch vertically.

```
void BuildObjectProperties(Container parent, List<ObjectProperty> objectProperties)
{
    var verticalBox = new VBox(false, 0);
    foreach (var objectProperty in objectProperties)
    {
        BuildObjectProperty(verticalBox, objectProperty);
    }
    parent.Add(verticalBox);
}

void BuildObjectProperty(Container parent, ObjectProperty objectProperty)
{
    switch (objectProperty.Type)
    {
        case PropertyType.Text:
            parent.Add(new Entry());
            break;
        case PropertyType.Number:
            parent.Add(new SpinButton(0,10,1));
            break;
        case PropertyType.Note:
            parent.Add(new TextView());
            break;
        case PropertyType.List:
            parent.Add(new TreeView());
            break;
        case PropertyType.Enum:
            parent.Add(new ComboBox());
            break;
        case PropertyType.Reference:
            parent.Add(new ComboBox());
            break;
    }
}
```

With this code the widgets get created and added but they all have an equal distribution on the frame (they are far apart) and I wanted the distance between them to be fixed (10px for example) also I wanted their height to be fixed as well despite the number of widgets present on screen.

Maybe Vbox is not really what I should be using but I don't really know how to do this other way. So I'm asking for some help :)

PS: Another thing (I don't know how many widgets there will be... so if there are too many I wanted to have a scroll bar to scroll the panel, some help on this would also be appreciated.) Thank you very much.

Comment: may be just use a Fixed instead of a VBox and then simply layout using the X / Y and the WidthRequest and HeightRequest of the child widgets you are adding

Answer (score 1):

I just found out what was the problem in my code and I came up with the solution. I just used PackStart instead of the simple Add method.

```
        Widget widget = null;
        switch (objectProperty.Type)
        {
            case PropertyType.Text:
                widget = new TextField(objectProperty.Name);
                break;
            case PropertyType.Number:
                widget = new SpinnerField(objectProperty.Name);
                break;
            case PropertyType.Note:
                widget = new NoteField(objectProperty.Name) { HeightRequest = 80 };
                break;
            case PropertyType.List:
                widget = new ListField(objectProperty.Name) { HeightRequest = 100 }; ;
                break;
            case PropertyType.Enum:
                widget = new ComboField(objectProperty.Name);
                break;
            case PropertyType.Reference:
                widget = new ComboField(objectProperty.Name);
                break;
        }
        parent.PackStart(widget, false, true, 8);
```

This way works!! Just to let you all know ;)